# Javascript if else statement with multiple or following condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm detecting extensions then taking actions based on the extension. So my question is why doesn't this work, seems logical enough eh?

```
var ext = url.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if (ext == 'avi' || 'mpg' || 'mpeg' || 'mp4' || '3gp') {
  This is a video (this always returns true...?)
} else if (ext == 'jpg' || 'jpeg' || 'gif' || 'png' || 'bmp') {
  This is a picture
} else {
  This extension isn't supported here
}
```

But this does? Unnecessary overhead?

```
var ext = url.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if (ext == 'avi' || ext == 'mpg' || ext == 'mpeg' || ext == 'mp4') {
  This is a video
} else if (ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'jpeg' || ext == 'gif' || ext == 'png') {
  This is a picture
} else {
  This extension isn't supported here
}
```

Is there a syntax issue I'm missing to make this work like example 1 without hitting the variable over and over? Concerned because this list is a lot larger than what is pictured in regards to the amount of extensions and seems like a lot of unnecessary code when it's all said and done.

Comment: `ext = 'jpg' || 'jpeg' ||` etc is the same as `(ext == 'jpg') || 'jpeg' ||` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `ext == 'avi' || 'mpg' || 'mpeg' || 'mp4' || '3gp'` will always be true as you are comparing if ext is `avi` or if any of `'mpg' || 'mpeg' || 'mp4' || '3gp'` are [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

The `==` operator only compares a single variable for future reference.

Another way you can write this comparison with a `switch` is as follows:

```
switch(ext) {//switch with fall throughs
    case 'avi':
    case 'mpg':
    case 'mpeg':
    case 'mp4':
        //we got a video
        break;
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'gif':
    case 'png':
        //its a picture
        break;
    default:
        //this extension isn't suupported
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and example of alternate method.

Answer (score 1):

> *"So my question is why doesn't this work"*

Because that's just not what the [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FLogical_Operators) does.

The shortest syntax I can think of to implement your concept is to use a regex test for each condition:

```
if (/^(avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|3gp)$/.test(ext)) {
```

Or you can use an array:

```
if (['avi', 'mpg', 'mpeg', 'mp4', '3gp'].indexOf(ext) != -1) {
```

(Assuming you're not worried about IE<=8, or are using [a shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility), or use jQuery's `$.inArray()` instead of `.indexOf()`.)

Or this seems an obvious place to use a `switch` statement:

```
var ext = url.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
switch(ext) {
    case 'avi':
    case 'mpg':
    case 'mpeg':
    case 'mp4':
    case '3gp':
       //  This is a video (this always returns true...?)
       break;
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'gif':
    case 'png':
    case 'bmp':
       // This is a picture
       break;
    default:
       //  This extension isn't supported here
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first `if` condition is always truthy.

If you have a lot of values to check then I would suggest something like

```
var video = ['avi', 'mpg'];
var audio = ['mpg', 'mpeg'];
if($.inArray(ext, video)){
    //video
} if($.inArray(ext, audio)){
    //audio
} else {
}
```